# How can I make a camera system more secure that has port forwarding enabled

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, port-forwarding, internet-security

I just want to know what I can do to make a more secure connection while my ports is forwarded to enable remote viewing of a camera system. I've done some research and got SSH tunneling and MAC filtering for alternative options but I don't know how secure SSH tunneling is and MAC filtering can be spoofed.

I also saw that you can use a VPN to forward the ports but my worry with this is will the change in IP not cause problems when I try to connect to the remote camera systems where the monitoring system is or can I only set the DVR and NVR to a static IP?

Any suggestions would help or  any recommendations for an extra layer of security on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH tunneling and MAC filtering is usually safe enough.

SSH tunneling is safely encrypted, and for MAC filtering to be spoofed the
hacker needs to know your MAC address to start with.

A VPN requires that one side in the connection has installed a VPN server,
and the other side a VPN client. This adds some complications and may not
be feasible for some types of surveillance cameras.

As long as you are looking for protection from the occasional hacker,
SSH tunneling and MAC filtering with good long passwords is good enough.

An error often done by online camera owners is to not change the default
password that came with the camera system. Once you have done that
and chosen a long and hard password,
you have already achieved a good measure of security.